# Tkinter ejecuta siempre al inicio las funciones?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Estoy realizando una aplicación con Python y la librería Tkinter, y me encuentro con algunas dudas.

En primer lugar, estoy haciendo uso de clases, a dato informativo.

```
class FrameUno(customtkinter.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        ...
        self.createWidgets()


    def createWidgets(self):
        ...
        self.errors()


    def errors(self):
        ...
        if trucu == 1:
            self.funcion()

        self.after(..., lambda: errors())
  

    def funcion(self):
        ...
```

Mi problema, es que esa primera llamada a la def funcion, se ejecuta desde el inicio, es decir, en el 1er arranque, pero yo no quiero que pase eso, sólo quiero que pase cuándo se cumpla el if.

Sé que esto pasa, porque cuándo debuggeo la app, si pongo el break en la parte del if, la app se ejecuta de forma normal, hasta que llegue a esa parte de código, pero si pongo otro dentro del código de la def funcion, se ejecuta antes de poder usar la app de forma correcta.

Mi duda es, ¿las funciones se ejecutan siempre al inicio? ¿Cómo funciona realmente el poner *lambda:* delante?

Gracias a tod@s!

Comment: Hola Pinkurauchin, Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: En ese ejemplo, claro que se va a ejecutar todo porque en el constructor está llamando al método `createWidgets()` y este método a su vez llama a `errors()`. Este último llamará a `funcion()` si detecta que `trucu = 1`. Al método especial `__init__()` se le conoce como [constructor](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+que+es+constructor), el cual es ejecutado automáticamente cuando la clase es instanciada en un objeto. Esto es algo conceptual, así que debes estudiar un poquito más sobre [POO en Python](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+programacion+orientada+a+objetos).

Comment: Si bien no se puede hablar de "error", normalmente, el constructor de la clase no llama a otros métodos, como su nombre lo indica, se usa para "construir" el objeto. sin ver el código completo de la clase, no puedo agregar más.

Comment: @aeportugal , sí, eso lo entiendo, el problema, es que no pasa por esa parte del if, porque es false, pero igualmente se ejecuta, jajaja